# add single query string and array of queries to form

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple form on my site http://www.example.com

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" name="name">
</form>
```

How do I get my form to look like this

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="tom" name="name">
</form>
```

If I type in (or a user is taken to this page from a search page) http://www.example.com?name=tom

bearing in mind at some point my form may look like this.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value="" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" value="" name="name[]">
</form>
```

so I would like to handle an array of names as well.  I have had a look at [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) but can't get my head around how I would do this. Is it possible without submitting to a server side language sucha as php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no baked-in jQuery way to get name/value pairs from the querysting to javascript variables (though, shouldn't there be??)

But folks have written  pure javascript functions to do that for you:  [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

If you use the 2nd answer to the above question, by [Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e), you can capture all the querystring vars to name-value pairs of a javascript object. Here's what he wrote:

```
var urlParams = {};
(function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

Then use these to set the form values of inputs with the same name as the querystring names with jQuery like this:

```
$.each(urlParams, function(key, value){
    $('form [name=' + key + ']').val(value);
});
```

**Update:** since this is hard to test in jsFiddle, here is an entire web page as a working example. It will replace the values 'a', 'b', and 'c' with those passed in by the url ('1', '2', and '3') -- just set this up as test.html on localhost and go to: `http://localhost/test.html?a=1&b=2&c=3`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Test URL params</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
            var urlParams = {};
            (function () {
                var match,
                pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
                search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
                decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
                query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

                while (match = search.exec(query))
                   urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
            })();

            $.each(urlParams, function(key, value){
                $('form [name=' + key + ']').val(value);
            });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input name="a" value ="a" /><input name="b" value ="a" /><input name="c" value ="a" />
</form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Do you know of a working example of this?  I can't seem to get it working and it is hard to test in a fiddle?